# VS2019 Add Project Property page

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsx

I am trying to extend the VS2019 project properties page and add a new one but I can't get to work if I use the Microsoft guide:

[Adding and removing property pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-and-removing-property-pages?view=vs-2019)

Does anyone maybe have a sample code?

EDIT:

[My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Yf6k.png)

I currently have and normal VSIX Project that I used to create an Editor package and added menu items successfully. I basically just want to add a project property page that will be used on all "Class Library" projects.

Comment: Can you provide some information on what you have tried so far. Do you have your `IVsHierarchy` implementation in place?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone maybe have a sample code?

Actually, follow the guidance and you can get what you want.

Follow this guidance:

**Remove a property page**

1) create a vsix c# project in VS2019 IDE and then add a new class like `RemovePage`

2) then add these namespaces in this file:

```
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

and implement the `IVsHierarchy` interface and add its implementation methods.

3) After that, on the bottom of the page, add the main function to realize it:

```
protected int GetProperty(uint itemId, int propId, out object property)
        {
            //Use propId to filter configuration-independent property pages.
            switch (propId)
            {

                case (int)__VSHPROPID2.VSHPROPID_PropertyPagesCLSIDList:
                    {
                        //Get a semicolon-delimited list of clsids of the configuration-independent property pages


                        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(GetProperty(itemId, propId, out property));
                        string propertyPagesList = ((string)property).ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        //Remove the property page here

                        string buildEventsPageGuid = "{1E78F8DB-6C07-4D61-A18F-7514010ABD56}";
                        int index = propertyPagesList.IndexOf(buildEventsPageGuid);
                        if (index != -1)
                        {
                            // GUIDs are separated by ';' so if you remove the last GUID, also remove the last ';'
                            int index2 = index + buildEventsPageGuid.Length + 1;
                            if (index2 >= propertyPagesList.Length)
                                propertyPagesList = propertyPagesList.Substring(0, index).TrimEnd(';');
                            else
                                propertyPagesList = propertyPagesList.Substring(0, index) + propertyPagesList.Substring(index2);


                        }
                        //New property value
                        property = propertyPagesList;

                        break; 
                    }

            }
```

**Add a property page**

1) add a new class called `DeployPropertyPage` and implement Form and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IPropertyPage`. After it, add the implementation method as prompted.

2) add these namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using MSVSIP = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
```

3) change the default function `GetPageInfo` into:

```
 public void GetPageInfo(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.PROPPAGEINFO[] pPageInfo)
        {
            PROPPAGEINFO info = new PROPPAGEINFO();
            info.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROPPAGEINFO));
            info.dwHelpContext = 0;
            info.pszDocString = null;
            info.pszHelpFile = null;
            info.pszTitle = "Deployment";  //Assign tab name
            info.SIZE.cx = this.Size.Width;
            info.SIZE.cy = this.Size.Height;
            if (pPageInfo != null && pPageInfo.Length > 0)
                pPageInfo[0] = info;
        }
```

4) add the main function as the document said on the bottom of the file:

```
protected int GetProperty(uint itemId, int propId, out object property)
        {
            //Use propId to filter configuration-dependent property pages.
            switch (propId)
            {

           case (int)__VSHPROPID2.VSHPROPID_CfgPropertyPagesCLSIDList:
            {
                //Get a semicolon-delimited list of clsids of the configuration-dependent property pages.
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(GetProperty(itemId, propId, out property));
                //Add the Deployment property page.
                property += ';' + typeof(DeployPropertyPage).GUID.ToString("B");

                 break;
            }
        }

       return GetProperty(itemId, propId, out property);
    }
```

5) then register your new property page before the class name `DeployPropertyPage`.

```
[MSVSIP.ProvideObject(typeof(DeployPropertyPage), RegisterUsing = RegistrationMethod.CodeBase)]
```

**Update 1**

**DeployPropertyPage**like these:

```
class DeployPropertyPage:IPropertyPage
    {
        public void SetPageSite(IPropertyPageSite pPageSite)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Activate(IntPtr hWndParent, RECT[] pRect, int bModal)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Deactivate()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void GetPageInfo(PROPPAGEINFO[] pPageInfo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetObjects(uint cObjects, object[] ppunk)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Show(uint nCmdShow)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Move(RECT[] pRect)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int IsPageDirty()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Apply()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Help(string pszHelpDir)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int TranslateAccelerator(MSG[] pMsg)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**RemovePage** like this:

```
 class RemovePage: IVsHierarchy
    {
        public int SetSite(Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider psp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetSite(out Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider ppSP)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int QueryClose(out int pfCanClose)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Close()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetGuidProperty(uint itemid, int propid, out Guid pguid)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int SetGuidProperty(uint itemid, int propid, ref Guid rguid)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetProperty(uint itemid, int propid, out object pvar)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int SetProperty(uint itemid, int propid, object var)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetNestedHierarchy(uint itemid, ref Guid iidHierarchyNested, out IntPtr ppHierarchyNested, out uint pitemidNested)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetCanonicalName(uint itemid, out string pbstrName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int ParseCanonicalName(string pszName, out uint pitemid)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Unused0()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int AdviseHierarchyEvents(IVsHierarchyEvents pEventSink, out uint pdwCookie)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int UnadviseHierarchyEvents(uint dwCookie)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Unused1()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Unused2()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Unused3()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Unused4()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And then you can modify your code in these methods.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is very detailed and helpful. I Created the form and added the 2 Interfaces "IPropertyPage, IVsHierarchy" also registered the "ProvideObject".
Unfortunately it is still not showing for some reason and not sure what I am missing. Do I need to create a Package and Factory class for the project?

Comment: What error message did you face? When you inheritance these interface, you should realize their methods. If you miss them, you should add them. And you would better use two classes to implement their interfaces separately in case they are in a mess.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me. I did exactly as you suggested. but none of the interface methods are being hit. Please see the image link "My Project" in my original post. It is a screenshot of what I have

Comment: try to create a new item called Async package and then realize your class object in it.You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-project-properties?view=vs-2019).